# Passing the value of a select_datetime component into the controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Ruby on Rails web application in which I have several select_datetime components in the view.

In the controller, it returns the value for one of the select_datetime components in the :date param, but not both.

So, how do you pass the value for more than one select_datetime components into the corresponding controller?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: Sure - there's not much to it

Comment: Here is my code in the view file  <%= select_datetime(Time.now + 3600, options = {}, html_options = {}) %>

Comment: No, I mean the _complete_ code. You are talking about several `select_datetime` components, but you show only one. And please put the code in your question rather than pasting as a comment.